# Failed to start cassandra.service: Unit cassandra.service not found

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I uninstalled cassandra 3.10 and reinstalled 3.11
when i starting cassandra through 
sudo service cassandra start

getting error

Failed to start cassandra.service: Unit cassandra.service not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `cassandra.service` in `/etc/systemd/system` as below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Cassandra Cluster Node Daemon

[Service]
Type=forking
user=cassandra
ExecStart=/etc/cassandra/bin/cassandra
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/rm -rf /data/cassandra/saved_caches
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This is the fine result:

[image]

Remember that `ExecStart` is the cassadra's path installed.

P.S. If there isn't the cassandra user, you can create `sudo adduser cassandra`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you. I've fixed my issue with the "CENTOS service fix" section

https://docs.nomagic.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20841857